# How to set mark on packet when forwarding it in nat prerouting table?

Tags: networking, iptables, routing, nat, port-forwarding

I have a few port forward rules like this

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 46000 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.16.8.2:46000
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 172.16.8.2 --dport 46000 -j ACCEPT
```

I wonder if there is a way to add new forward rules in one line instead of two so I don't have to enter the same data twice. I mean rules like this:

1. In nat PREROUTING forward packet to destination and mark it
2. In filter FORWARD allow all packets that were marked using rule 1

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to get this done with only one command per DNAT – unless... see below. But it is possible to enter the data just once.

Let's define the mark range 1024–2047 for connections which get DNATted and forwarded.

One line with each DNAT match condition in mangle:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 46000 -j MARK --set-mark 0x400
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 46001 -j MARK --set-mark 0x401
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 46002 -j MARK --set-mark 0x402
```

One command for each in nat:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -m mark --mark 0x400 -j DNAT \
  --to-destination 172.16.8.2:46000
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -m mark --mark 0x401 -j DNAT \
  --to-destination 172.16.8.2:46001
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -m mark --mark 0x402 -j DNAT \
  --to-destination 172.16.8.2:46002
```

One command for all in filter:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m mark --mark 0x400/0x400 -j ACCEPT
```

BTW: There is no need to give the destination port for `-j DNAT` if it is not changed.

**Edit 1:**

You can do that if you do without allowing the connections explicitly, if you are fine with allowing everything that has been DNATted. In that case you would stick to your

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 46000 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.16.8.2:46000
```

but have only one FORWARD rule for all:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate DNAT -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: That's still 2 commands for each port, one in mangle and one in nat

Comment: @Poma That's correct and when I realized that I was going to write a different answer ("It's not possible"). But then I also noticed that you did not only ask for a one command solution (which is impossible according to my understanding) but also for "not entering the data twice". And at least that is the case with my solution.

Comment: @Poma See the edit: There is a one command solution which is not equivalent but similar to your original rule set.

Comment: yes that's just what I need

Comment: How to set mark by the hostname?

Comment: Could I do the same with UDP? I'm trying a similar solution but the packets do not arrive to the nat table.

Comment: @kato2 UDP packets certainly go through the nat table. Maybe you used PREROUTING where you would have needed OUTPUT.

Comment: @HaukeLaging you might be right, however adding this rule after the current ones, solved the issue
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 46000 -j CONNMARK --save-mark